# Why does this code say I need a class/struct/union?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I've been programming in java and AS3 and C# for some time, and decided to give C++ a try... So, I decided to create a simple program to see how objects work here. I have two files:

***Human.h***

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Human
{
    private:
        int _age;
        string _name;
        bool _gender;

    public:
        void setAge(int);
        void setName(string);
        int getAge();
        string getName();
        bool getGender();


    Human(int age, string name, bool gender)
    { 
        setAge(age);
        setName(name);
        _gender = gender;
    }

    ~Human()
    {
    }
};

int Human::getAge(){
    return _age;
}

string Human::getName(){
    return _name;
}

bool Human::getGender(){
    return _gender;
}

void Human::setAge(int val){

}

void Human::setName(string val){
    _name = val;
}
```

And ***Main.cpp***

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Human.h"
#include <string>


using namespace std;
void main(void){


Human *me;
me = new Human(27,"Mr Miyagi",true);

cout << "My name is "+me.getName()+" and I am "+me.getAge()+" years old";

}
```

What I get is a red line under the "me" word, and an *error C2228: left of '.getName' must have class/struct/union*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared me as a pointer.  <s>Either remove the `*` on the declaration, or</s>  Use `me->GetName()` etc to use it.

= = = edit = = =

Since there is no default constructor, the `*` must remain.  Either that or change it to

```
Human me(27, "name", true);
```

Comment: Thanks! Using the me->getName() made the program run! Now it gives me a -8923454 for age, but I guess I can fix it from there ;)

Comment: @Loupax - Because, your `setAge()` does nothing.

Comment: 1st) Duh! I noticed just now the empty setAge. 2nd) I had no idea I could create an object without using "new"... I think I'll go buy a book or something...

Comment: @Loupax - Buy books mentioned in this link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 2):

`me` is a *pointer to* a `Human` - so you need to use `->`

`cout` expects you to use the `<<` operator.

`main` should not return void, but int.

always `delete` what you `new`

```
int main() {
  Human *me;
  me = new Human(27,"Kostas Loupasakis",true);
  cout << "My name is " << me->getName() << " and I am " << me->getAge() << " years old";
  delete me;
}
```

Alternatively, you can do without the pointer, and use `.`:

```
int main() {
  Human me(27,"Kostas Loupasakis",true);
  cout << "My name is " << me.getName() << " and I am " << me.getAge() << " years old";
}
```

The first variant above allocates a Human from the free store, called heap - similar to java. You need to explicitly delete in c++ though.

The second variant allocates a Human on *stack* - java can only do this with primitive types (int, float) and so on, c++ can do this with any object. In this case, `me` is automatically destructed when it goes out of scope, at the final '}' in main.

Answer (score 1):

It should be -

```
cout << "My name is " << me->getName() << "and I am " << me->getAge() << " years old";
```

`me` is a pointer to an object. So, it's members should be accessed by operator `->`.

---

Also, note that `Human::setAge()` function does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Others have addressed the direct problem you asked about.  If you will indulge me, let me address a tangential issue.

Here is what you started with.

```
void main()
{
    // You could combine these two lines like this:
    //    Human *me = new Human(27,"Kostas Loupasakis",true);
    Human *me;
    me = new Human(27,"Kostas Loupasakis",true);

    cout << "My name is "+me->getName()+" and I am "+me->getAge()+" years old";
}
```

I can't speak to AS3, but in java and C#, you have the garbage collector to clean up allocated memory.  There is no such beast in C++, so you have to clean up the memory yourself like this.

```
void main()
{
    Human *me = new Human(27,"Kostas Loupasakis",true);

    cout << "My name is "+me->getName()+" and I am "+me->getAge()+" years old";

    delete me;
}
```

The call to `new` allocates the `Human` object on the heap, and `delete` frees the memory when you are done with it.  Here is a better way to do it.

```
void main()
{
    Human me(27,"Kostas Loupasakis",true);

    cout << "My name is "+me.getName()+" and I am "+me.getAge()+" years old";
}
```

In this case, space for the `Human` object is reserved on the stack as opposed to the heap.  Thus, the space is automatically reclaimed when the function exits.  Additionally, you can use the `.` notation instead of the `->` notation since you are dealing with an object as opposed to a pointer.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This was a very informing post! I didn't know about the usage of delete, I thought I should use ~me or something (didn't try it yet). Also the ClassName instance(parameter1,2,3) notation was new to me... Isn't it basically the same as using the new operator? PS: AS3 doesn't have neither garbage collector, nor destructors. It's all about using the same objects again, and again...

Comment: Both mechanisms call the same constructor.  Using `new`, though, causes the object to be allocated on the heap as opposed to the stack.  In general, prefer the stack if possible, especially for function-level variables.

Answer (score 0):

the object 'me' is actually a pointer, so therefore you will need to use an arrow instead of a dot.

```
me->getname();
```

will solve the error.